# Does constructing a QFileInfo object result in file system accesses?

Tags: c++, qt

When running the this sample code from QFileInfo documentation:

```
 QFileInfo fi("/tmp/archive.tar.gz");
 QString base = fi.baseName();  // base = "archive"
```

Would it result in accesses to the file system?

I'm assuming that calling `fi.lastModified()` or `fi.exists()` would require the file system to be accessed, but what about it I only use it to extract parts of the file name (extension, base file name, only the directory, etc.)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without looking at the implementation of methods it is hard to say precisely which method access the filesystem and which not. But I found in the library this sort of explanation that answer your question:

> #### Performance Issues
>
> Some of `QFileInfo`'s functions query the file
>   system, but for performance reasons, some functions only operate on
>   the file name itself. For example: To return the absolute path of a
>   relative file name, `absolutePath()` has to query the file system. The
>   `path()` function, however, can work on the file name directly, and so
>   it is faster.
>
> **Note:** To speed up performance, `QFileInfo` caches
>   information about the file. Because files can be changed by other
>   users or programs, or even by other parts of the same program, there
>   is a function that refreshes the file information: `refresh()`. If you
>   want to switch off a `QFileInfo`'s caching and force it to access the
>   file system every time you request information from it call
>   `setCaching(false)`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question, so I studied Qt source code. Version 462 to be exact. Also, my focus was specifically the `QFileInfo` constructor that takes a `QString` (as illustrated in original question code).

This constructor invokes `QAbstractFileEngine::create` which itself makes 2 noticeable calls:

1. `QDir::searchPaths()`
2. `new QFSFileEngine()`

Given my understanding of these 2 operations, I am fairly confident that this constructor **does not access a file system**, but rather preps up `QFileInfo` up to perform such operations with the file name provided in the native environment (file path conventions like Unix versus MS-DOS).

One thing to consider is that this statement / code is subject to change at any time. So, unless Qt's documentation directly calls out that it does not access a file system, there are no promises my answer will always be correct.